# Html Form "Action Attribute"

Tags: html, forms

I'm learning to code and encounter a problem with making a form using HTML.

In the book, it stated that "every `<form>` element requires an action attribute and its value is the URL for the page on the server that will receive the information in the form when it is submitted."

But I thought about it for a long time, and I couldn't figure it out. What is meant by "the URL for the page on the server". If I got a site uploaded to a web hosting company, I would need to get it there? Or I need to rent a server elsewhere so that I will get one? Or it just fine to be store on a local file? Because I saw the data need to be processed by PHP, although I don't know whats that.

Can anyone help me with this? Really appreciated.

Regards,
Ace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTTP(S) URL will include a hostname (which identifies a computer (acting as a server) on a network) and a path (and possibly some other components which don't matter for this question).

When you type a URL into the address bar of a browser, the browser will make a request to the server and ask for whatever is at the path.

The server will respond (typically with some data like an HTML document).

The server has to perform some logic to decide what to respond with. Typically this will either be:

- Reading a file from its hard disk and returning the contents *or*
- Executing a program and generating some content programmatically

When you submit a form, you are making a request to a URL with some data attached to it. Almost all of the time you will want the server to execute a program and do *something* with that data (such as put it in a database).

The program that gets executed can be written in any programming language you like (such as Perl, PHP, JavaScript, Java, or whatever).

---

> If I got a site uploaded to a web hosting company, I would need to get it there?

Typically, if you have web hosting already then you will use that web hosting for any server-side programming you need to do.

If the hosting service doesn't provide you with any server-side hosting options (i.e. if it is just static hosting such as you might find from Github Pages). Then that isn't an option. Likewise if the server-side options they program aren't suitable for you (e.g. they only support PHP but you want to run something written in Node.js) then you'll have to find an alternative.

The two alternatives you have are:

1. Move everything to hosting that provides the features you want
2. Host something elsewhere and keep the majority of your site in the original hosting

(There is nothing wrong with the latter option, I have one site which uses Amazon S3 static hosting for most of it but has a couple of web services running in Heroku).

> Or I need to rent a server elsewhere so that I will get one?

Dedicated hosting is almost certainly very expensive overkill for your purposes.

> Or it just fine to be store on a local file?

It isn't possible to do server-side programming with a `file:` scheme URL. There's no server to execute the program.

If you are only working locally then you can install a web server on your computer. This is normal for development purposes.

---

It is probably worth mentioning that there are a few common server-side programs which are available prewritten with hosting services (e.g. contact forms which email you when someone fills them in). These typically come with advertising and require that the `<form>` and its contents are constructed with the specific fields the service expects. If you look for one of these be careful to follow their instructions precisely.

---

Aside: The statement that the action attribute is required is flat out wrong. It is an optional attribute and in its absence the form will be submitted to the URL of the current page.

Comment: I have to say your explanation is very detailed and professional. But there's still something that I'm getting confused about. 

I'm using Hostinger as my web hosting provider. I'm not sure what is server-side programming and if Hostinger is providing in my plan. Is this what you mention here: https://www.hostinger.com/php-hosting, so after I purchase then I will get a link to put in? But How do I get the data from the server then?

Comment: You won't "get a link" any more then you do now. Currently, I assume you upload files (like HTML documents and images) and the filename becomes part of the URL. A basic use of PHP works exactly the same way, you upload a `something.php` file and then you run it by visiting `http://example.com/example.php`. *You will need to write the PHP code* (or find something suitable that someone else has written already).

Comment: Well, that's still complicated for me as you can imagine I'm just a student who's learning Html and CSS for now. How do I understand those PHP and nodejs...In the past, I've tried using a plugin call Elementor in WordPress. When customers submitted the form, then the info will send to my mail and I'm able to watch it. Is this also done by what is so called "PHP" or "nodejs"?

Comment: Your server side code can do whatever you like with the data, including sending emails with it in.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a front-end tool that allows you to take inputs using a form from the user. once the user clicks the submit button a post request is sent to the back-end tool (PHP in this casse; PHP is a back-end programming language). the back-end tool handles the information given and deals with it to your liking. the action attribute is basically telling the front-end (HTML) where to give the information to the back-end(PHP) which is in the form of a URL.

i highly suggest trying out this example on W3schools :

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: I'm building a site only with Html and CSS. I have no idea what is meant by a PHP. 

How do I get the data once I put "action_page.php" into the action attribute after the customer has submitted the form?

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to send your HTML form data to a PHP script. You can use WAMP server or XAMP server to do this locally. You should use the PHP script file path as the input for the .
For instance,
Home.html

```
<HTML>
....
<form action="process.php">
...
</form>
</HTML>
```

So, when you submit the form , the form data is passed onto the PHP file which you can access using a $_[SUBMIT] super global array in your PHP script.
Check github for projects on HTML,JAVASCRIPT,PHP.
Here's one to start: https://github.com/kristej/Uniform-Database-Management.git
If you are sending the data to an online server, you need to own it to process it. Hence try it out locally first.

Comment: Hi, I have zero knowledge about PHP and that's why I don't understand what you mean by "using a $_[SUBMIT] super global array in your PHP script." If I know about it then I will just make it and put it into the action attribute...